# How to resize to my uiwebview frame size m.youtube player?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube

P.S. If you had use `UC Browser` on iPad you will understand, what Im talking about!

Im building youtube integration in my app and I have some problems.
I was used embed videos and put it on `uiwebview`. But when I tried to play some `vevo/bbc/apple` etc videos, it said that playback is restrited.

So I was looking for solution. And first though is: use m.youtube player. There is everthing what I need, but I want this in small `UIWebview(320x240)` in right/buttom corner. Player of course is biger, and not fit in `UIwebview` bounds.size.

How can I "hack it leggaly" and get only player from m. youtube and fit to size I need.
And if someone knows, what is the way how `UC Browser` receives video from every website's player on `mpmovieplayer` in floated window?

Comment: wevView.scalespagestofitwidth = yes for UIWEbview.This solves ur second problem.

Comment: thats set content really small on 320x240.